# water not following a path even after adding path constraint

Tags: fluid-simulation, parent

I created a pipe in 3d. water does not follow the path but starts falling downwards. So, I added path constraint (follow path curve object) inside the pipe for the source object. My source object is following the path but not water. I have been trying to solve this over week now.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZkH7ndNS-HF8Ywx3AEyKLmDxIX_z_kEy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please tell us, what you want to achieve? Do you want the water running down the pipe? The water follows physics. So as long as you have gravity and no other force involved, it will follow gravity...and fall down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want something like this:

[image]

you need to:

1. close the pipe on the left side with a face
2. solidify the pipe to give it some thickness
3. flip faces
4. increase resolution divisions > 100 (mine was made with 100, and you still see it's permeable

Let Blender calculate the simulation and run it...